# How to configure PHP to catch fatal error using try catch?

Tags: php, exception, fatal-error

I know that we try catch in PHP to catch Exceptions, but about half of my interviewers said that try catch can catch a fatal error. I tried it and it doesn't work that way by default. Function set_error_handler can catch errors. And now I have doubts. Is there some way to configure PHP so it can catch a fatal error (or other errors) with try catch? I got doubts, because I found this pieces of code in my project

```
try {
//sometimes $sFile is not initialized 
    $sPath = $sProducerOutput . $sFile;
} catch (\Exception $oException) {
    $sPath = false;
}

try {
    $sJson = json_encode($aArgs['sJson']);
}
catch(\Exception $oException) {
    $bError    = true;
    $sMessage .= 'Unable to json_encode: ' . print_r($aArgs['sJson'], true) . ')'."\n";
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: None of these snippets should produce a *fatal* error. They won't by default produce catchable exceptions either, unless you turn them into exceptions.

Comment: Yes, they don't throw exception but they can produce warnings. So is it possible to configure PHP so that it throws exception instead of warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Comment: No, It's not a duplicate. I know there is a function which handles errors. My question that about try catch.